# Is there an R function to make a plot with not equally spaced axis?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to make a plot with not equally spaced axis.　Here is my data.

```
group <- c("group1","group2","group3","group4","group5","group6")
value <- c(520,550,13,15,30,20)
df <- cbind.data.frame(group,value)
```

I want to make a plot like this.
[idealplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLOTL.png)

I tried to make it using ggplot, like this.

```
ggplot(df,aes(x=factor(group),y=value))+geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

This code makes a plot with equally spaced axis which I do not want. This plot is unable to compare group 3,4,5 and 6. If you know how to make the ideal plot, please let me know. 
[undesiredplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hd4vA.png)

Comment: By "not equeally spaced" I assume you are referring to the continuity break of the Y axis in the linked axample?

Comment: Yes. You are right.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think I've ever seen a discontinuous axis in ggplot2.

With points instead of bars, you can fake a discontinuous axis by using facets:

```
ggplot(df,aes(x=factor(group),y=value)) +
    facet_grid(value < 100 ~., scales='free_y') +
    geom_point(stat="identity") + 
    theme(strip.text = element_blank())
```

[image: discontinuous Y emulated with facets]

Other alternatives to visualizing data with large differences in values is to log-transform or sqrt-transform the Y axis, which effectively stretches out small values and compresses large values.

```
ggplot(df,aes(x=factor(group),y=value)) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
    scale_y_log10() +
    annotation_logticks(base=10, sides='lr')
```

[image: specify]

Comment: Thank you cymon. Your ideas are great. And your question gave me a hint and then I searched "break axis". I could find the code below and this is close(not exact) to what I want. library(plotrix); gap.barplot(df$value,gap=c(50,500))